# Only last of multiple ajax requests gets completed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a script that allows me to make a ajax call with few lines of code. The script works with one ajax request, but when it comes to handling multiple request at once it fails. What have I done wrong ?

The code only processes the last request, while leaving the others "loading ...".

Here's my code:

```
/****************
  Related Javascript inside the HTML document
****************/
// First request
var ajax1 = new ajax_class();
ajax1.meth = "GET";
ajax1.file = "ajax_info.txt";
ajax1.elem = "results";
ajax1.send = null;
ajax1.ajax_call(ajax1.meth, ajax1.file, ajax1.elem, ajax1.send);

...

// Third request
var ajax3 = new ajax_class();
ajax3.meth = "GET";
ajax3.file = "ajax_info3.txt";
ajax3.elem = "results3";
ajax3.send = null;
ajax3.ajax_call(ajax3.meth, ajax3.file, ajax3.elem, ajax3.send);

/****************
  Related HTML inside the HTML document
****************/

<body>
<div id="results">Nothing has happend yet for 1....</div>
<div id="results2">Nothing has happend yet for 2 ....</div>
<div id="results3">Nothing has happend yet for 3 ....</div>
</body>


/****************
  Related code inside the JAVASCRIPT document
****************/

function ajax_class () {

this.meth = "GET";
this.file;
this.elem;
this.send = null;

this.ajax_call = function (meth, file, elem, send) {
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
           _id(elem).innerHTML = x.responseText;
        }
        else {
            _id(elem).innerHTML = "Loading ...";
        }
    }
    x.open(meth , file, true);
    x.send(send);
}
}
```

---

Works now, just had to add the "var" in front of x variable

Comment: If you found a solution, add it as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

It's at least partially because each `new XMLHttpRequest` is being set to the same global `x`, which can only keep 1 of them. This means later references to `x.readState` and `x.responseText` aren't always referring to the "*correct*" instance.

You'll want to [declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `x` when or before setting it so it's scoped and unique to each Ajax request:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

For more info, see [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488).

Comment: Not "possibly", it's exactly what's happening.

Comment: @just_dont I wrote that because I don't know if this the only issue. But, revised to clarify.

Comment: It works perfectly now, that I used the "var" -- Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of jQuery, your code will become much more simple

```
    function firstAjaxCall() {
      return $.get('/first');
    }

    function secondAjaxCall() {
      return $.get('/second');
    }

    function doFinalWork() {
      //wrap up
    }

    $.when( firstAjaxCall(), secondAjaxCall() )
      .done(function() {
        doFinalWork();
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log( 'Something is wrong, go fix it.' );
    });
```